# Visual Studio Can't debug CMake project - fails with "Unable to start program..."

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging, cmake

When I create a project using Cmake, Visual Studio is unable to debug the application. It fails with the error:
Unable to start program '....PATHTOPROGRAM' Access is denied.
The project seems to build ok, just can't debug. 
Projects created just with VS are fine

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, CMake doesn't setup `Debugging` section of the generated project. I always had to do this manually. Fortunately, it is not that hard:

- Choose any project you like, `ALL_BUILD`, for instance;
- Open `Properties -> Deugging`;
- Set `Debug Target` to the executable you want to debug from you build dir.

Even better, Visual Studio somehow keeps these settings even after CMake regenerate project files.

Comment: @ Ben, any update? If arrowd's reply is helpful for you, you could mark it as the answer. Have a nice day:)

Comment: I can't find `Debug Target` in `Properties -> Deugging`